# Hyperplane section of product of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of positive characteristic. Let $X$ be the product of finitely many connected smooth projective $k$-schemes of dimension $1,$ with $\dim_k X\geq 2$. Fix some closed $k$-immersion into projective space and take a hyperplane section (the immersion is arbitrary, it does not have to come from Segre embedding).

It the hyperplane section happens to be smooth as a $k$-scheme, is it necessarily isomorphic, as a $k$-scheme, to the product of finitely many connected smooth projective $k$-schemes of dimension 1?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  That is almost never the case.  Consider already a general hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^1_k\times_{\text{Spec}\ k}\mathbb{P}^1_k\times_{\text{Spec}\ k}\mathbb{P}^1_k$ in the complete linear system of the very ample invertible sheaf $\text{pr}_1^*\mathcal{O}(1)\otimes \text{pr}_2^*\mathcal{O}(1)\otimes \text{pr}_3^*\mathcal{O}(1)$.  For any two of the factors, the projection of the hypersurface to $\mathbb{P}^1_k\times_{\text{Spec}\ k}\mathbb{P}^1_k$ is birational, equivalent to a blowing up at $2$ points.  This hypersurface is not isomorphic to a product of curves.

Comment: @AknazarKazhymurat.  "is there an example where there is no birational map to a product of curves?"  Yes, there is.  Consider a general hypersurface in the complete linear system of the very ample invertible sheaf $\text{pr}_1^*\mathcal{O}(2)\otimes \text{pr}_2^*\mathcal{O}(2)\otimes \text{pr}_3^*\mathcal{O}(2)$.  This hypersurface is a K3 surface.  A K3 surface is not birational to a product of curves: since it is simply connected, such a birational transformation would be to a product of rational curves.  There are unirational K3 surfaces, but there are no rational K3 surfaces.